# Dropbox Core IOS - Detect successful account link

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, dropbox-api

I am using the dropbox core api through xamarin in c#.  I have pretty much everything figured out, the link itself is not the problem.  What I want is a way to detect if the user was successfully linked after a call to LinkFromController.  Something like this.

```html
if (!Session.SharedSession.IsLinked)
{
    Session.SharedSession.LinkFromController(self);
    Session.SharedSession.SuccessfulLink += (object linkSender, SharedSessionSuccessfulLinkEventArgs e2) =>
    {
        restClient.LoadMetadata("");
    };
}
```

I have found no evidence such a thing exists.  While the app works without this, it does interrupt the flow.

Comment: I can't speak to the Xamarin component, but for reference, the Dropbox iOS Core SDK it's built on handles this via `openURL`: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/ios

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  While it's not exactly what I wanted, I was able to get something working.